# Pointcut on native method call

Tags: java, gradle, aspectj

I have a problem where I need to have a `pointcut` on a logging function

```
@Pointcut(call(void org.slf4j.Logger.info(String)))
```

I am using compile time weaving and I can see that my classes are woven and the classes in `slf4j` are added to my classpath. The issue is that the `pointcut` is still not hit.

I read that I have to remember to use the woven classes instead of the original classes.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: It would help greatly if you would show how you weave your classes (`pom.xml` if you're using Maven), how you build your classpath (`pom.xml` again, if you're running your app through Maven), and the source of your aspect class.

Comment: An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would also be extremely helpful. Without being able to reproduce your problem it is kinda difficult to help you. All anyone can provide at this point are wild guesses.